# Gem not working in rails project but in ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run test.rb (see below) as a separate ruby file from within my rails project it works fine but when I wrap it as a module to be called from a controller it gives me:

```
LoadError (no such file to load -- eventmachine):1 in 'ModuleTest'
```

The gem is installed (sudo gem install event machine and bundle install) and added to the gem file (gem 'eventmachine').

Could someone please advice on what it is that I'm missing?

Separate file (called through: $ ruby lib/test.rb):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'
require 'fiber'

def doStuff
end

doStuff
```

Module:

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'
require 'fiber'

module ModuleTest
def doStuff
end
end
```

Controller:

```
require 'moduletest'

class MyController < ApplicationController
doStuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
gem 'eventmachine'
```

Into your `Gemfile`. Then execute `bundle install`.

If you want to use a new gem in your rails project, you need to add it into `Gemfile`. To learn more, visit http://gembundler.com/

Comment: 1. In Gemfile, did you put `gem 'eventmachine'` in any group?

Comment: 2. What will happen if you execute `bundle exec ruby lib/test.rb` instead of `ruby lib/test.rb`?

Comment: Now it's getting interesting.. It gives me this (require 'eventmachine' is line 1): app/test1.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- em-http (LoadError)